# Writing a query for deleting duplicate records without deleting all duplicate rows

Tags: sql

Suppose Table A has a column B like:

```
tbl A

------------------------
column B

10

10

20

20

50

50

40
```

Then how to delete duplicate records? E.g. in the above column there are two "10"s, so only one should be get deleted. This is the condition, how to implement it?

Comment: What rdbms are you using?

Answer (score 2):

If you use SQL-Server(or other rdbms which support window functions) you can use `ROW_NUMBER`.

So this works in SQL-Server 2005 and upon:

```
WITH CTE  -- a common-table-expression which is similar to a subquery, increases readability
(
    SELECT ColumnB, RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ColumnB ORDER BY ColumnB)
    FROM dbo.TblA
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

I like this approach because it's easy to use a `SELECT` instead to see what I'm going to delete.

Answer (score 1):

This works with `Oracle` RDBMS

```
DELETE FROM table_A
      WHERE ROWID IN (
              SELECT rid
                FROM (SELECT ROWID rid,
                            ROW_NUMBER () OVER (PARTITION BY B ORDER BY ROWID) rn
                     FROM table_A)
             WHERE rn <> 1);
```